# Html Form Onclick function does not take dynamic value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, postgresql

I have a html table the gets its values from a postgres table,have used php to echo the table content.
There are n no of rows in my table, When I click on the row  I want the values of that row to be used in another function,
My code to populate the table with sql values is

```
 while($row1 = pg_fetch_assoc($result1)) { 
          echo "<tr>"
            . "<td>{$row1['name']}</td>"
            . "<td>{$row1['email']}</td>"
            . "<td>"
                    . "<form id='form_id'>"
                    . "<input type='hidden' id='cord' value=$row1['lat']>"
                   . "<input type='hidden' id='cord1' value=$row1['lon']>"
                    . "<a onclick='submit_by_id()' >view</a>" 
                    . "</form>"

             . "</td>"
            . "</tr>\n";
        }
      }
    ?>
```

The html table is displayed, But only the first row values are shown (in the alert box) when I click the onclick function , I don't know how to reset the form values on click or is there any other way to optimize it.

```js
function submit_by_id() {
       var geom=document.getElementById('cord').value;
       var geom1=document.getElementById('cord1').value;
       alert(geom);
       alert(geom1);
            }
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</a</th>
    <th>Email</th>
   
    <th>Click to view</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>name1</td>
<td>email1</td>
<td>
<form id='form_id'>
<input type='hidden' id='cord' value=15><input type='hidden' id='cord1' value=73><a onclick='submit_by_id()' >view</a>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>name2</td>
<td>email2</td>
<td>
<form id='form_id'>
<input type='hidden' id='cord' value=16><input type='hidden' id='cord1' value=78><a onclick='submit_by_id()'>view</a>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `$latlon` variable? Seems this is outside the loop and hence its getting the same value. Also you can't have elements with same `id`. IDs should always be unique.

Comment: HTML 101: IDs MUST be unique within an HTML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating using while loop, but it does not create dynamic form in each iteration. which means all form in row a same. and submit form does not specify which form to sumit. you can do something like this

```
while($row1 = pg_fetch_assoc($result1)) { 
   $i=0;
      echo "<tr>"
        . "<td>{$row1['name']}</td>"
        . "<td>{$row1['email']}</td>"
        . "<td>{$row1['device_id']}</td>"
        . "<td>{$row1['last_login']}</td>"
       . "<td>"
                . "<form id='form_id"$i."'>"
                . "<input type='hidden' id='cord".$i."' value=$latlon[0]>"
                . "<input type='hidden' id='cord1".$i."' value=$latlon[1]>"
                . "<a onclick='submit_by_id($i)' >view</a>" 
                . "</form>"

         . "</td>"
        . "</tr>\n";
   $i++; 
   }
  }
?>
```

in javascript

```
function submit_by_id(id) {
   var geom=document.getElementById('cord'+id).value;
   var geom1=document.getElementById('cord1'+id).value;
   alert(geom);
   alert(geom1);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks this helped, thou the  $i=0; should be outside the while loop.

Comment: Yes, you can keep.

Answer (score 0):

when you are using multiple rows, your id cord1 and cord also repeating. make it dynamically vary to each row or use class to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Well as the tags indicate jQuery is allowed so i use jQuery.

You should not have multiple elements with the same id. Use a class instead:

```
           . "<form id='form_id'>"
            . "<input type='hidden' class='cord' value=$latlon[0]>"
            . "<input type='hidden' class='cord1' value=$latlon[1]>"
            . "<a onclick='submit_by_id()' class='glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin'></a>" 
            . "</form>"
```

To access it a nice way is to use closest to find the form the element is in:

```
function submit_by_id() {
       var $form = $(this).closest('form'); 
       var geom= $form.find('.cord').val();
       var geom1= $form.find('.cord1').val();
       alert(geom);
       alert(geom1);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

ID should be unique, you need to use class in your case.
Change

```
id='cord' and id='cord1'
```

to

```
class='cord' and class='cord1'
```

And your JS code

```
function submit_by_id() {
   var geom=document.getElementById('cord').value;
   var geom1=document.getElementById('cord1').value;
   alert(geom);
   alert(geom1);
        }
```

to

```
function submit_by_id() {
           var $form = $(this).parent(); 
           var geom= $form.find('.cord').val();
           var geom1= $form.find('.cord1').val();
           alert(geom);
           alert(geom1);
    }
```